# Difference between [NSMutableData data] and [[NSMutableData alloc]init]

Tags: iphone, ios

I am doing JSON parsing in my App, When I Use **responseData = [NSMutableData data];** it crashes on [responseData setLength:0];

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

   [responseData setLength:0];   // CRASH HERE

}
```

and when I use **responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];** my program works fine. I already make property in .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData* responseData;
```

and synthesize in .m file

```
@synthesize responseData;
```

**Question :** what is difference between **[NSMutableData data]** and **[[NSMutableData alloc]init];**

thanks

Comment: try self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[NSMutableData data]` returns an autoreleased object whereas `[[NSMutableData alloc] init]` returns a retained object.

Answer (score 2):

`[NSMutableData data]` returns an `autorelease` object, i.e. it will be added to the auto-release pool and at the end of a frame a release will be called on that object and if reference count becomes 0 it will be cleaned from memory.

`[[NSMutableData alloc] init]` returns an object with reference count 1, and here you need to remove it from memory explicitly by calling `release`, once you are done.

So solution for your problem is:

```
// 1. retain explicitly
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

// 2. or else define
@property (retain, nonatomic)
```

The second option will retain the object. So even if `release` is called on `autorelease` pool it wont be flushed as its retained (reference count wont be zero)

As you are using `self.responseData`, its reference count increases by 1, so even if you assign `autorelease` object its gets retained due to declared property:

```
self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
```